# pip upgrade downloading every previous version until storage is full

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, centos7, aws-cli, pip

On CentOS 7, I am trying to upgrade awscli:

`/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install awscli --upgrade --user`

Why is this downloading every single previous version, until there is finally no space left on device?

> Requirement already satisfied: awscli in
> /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.18.196) Collecting awscli
> Downloading awscli-1.18.197-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)
> Downloading awscli-1.18.197.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.196-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.196.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.195-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.195.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.194-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.194.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.193-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.193.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.192-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.192.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.191-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.191.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.190-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.190.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.189-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.189.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.188-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.188.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.187-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.187.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.186-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.186.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.185-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.185.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.184-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.184.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.183-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.183.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.182-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.182.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.181-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.181.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.180-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.180.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.179-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.179.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.178-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.178.tar.gz (1.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.177-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.177.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.176-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.176.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.175-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.175.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.174-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.174.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.173-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.173.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.172-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.172.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.171-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.171.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.170-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.170.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.169-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.169.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.168-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.168.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.167-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.167.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.166-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.166.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.165-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.165.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.164-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.164.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.163-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.163.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.162-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.162.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.161-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.161.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.160-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.160.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.159-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.159.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.158-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.158.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.157-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.157.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.156-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.156.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.155-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.155.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.154-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.154.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.153-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.153.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.152-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.152.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.151-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.151.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.150-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.150.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.149-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.149.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.148-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.148.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> awscli-1.18.147-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.18.147.tar.gz (1.3 MB)   Using cached
> (...)
> awscli-1.16.41-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.41.tar.gz (636 kB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.40-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.40.tar.gz (636 kB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.39-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.39.tar.gz (636 kB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.38-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)   Downloading
> awscli-1.16.38.tar.gz (636 kB) ERROR: Could not install packages due
> to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device:
> '/tmp/pip-install-d05v14o4/awscli_799b59c34d714e6abf8745c33231bad6/awscli/examples/ec2/create-vpc-endpoint-connection-notification.rst'

I have uninstalled and re-installed it. Works well when I do that way.
But I don't understand why upgrading causes it to download every other version.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the reason is this: https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2020/11/pip-20-3-new-resolver.html

A new dependency resolver was released, and it's obviously causing this ridiculous infinite loop downloading all previous versions.

The article above mentions that `You can use the deprecated (old) resolver, using the flag --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver, until we remove it in the pip 21.0 release in January 2021.`

So, this resolved the problem for me:

`/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install awscli --upgrade --user --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver`

... until January 2021!

---

**Edit:**
This is actually fixed in the newest version of "pip":

`/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install 'pip==20.3.3'`

I had to specify "20.3.3", as otherwise the same infinite loop was happening trying to upgrade pip.

Comment: If this worked, it would be a very good idea to file a bug report!

Comment: @MichaelHampton see my update. Fixed in the latest version of pip.

Comment: I still see this issue in pip 21.1.1, but the `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` workaround fixed it for me.